# Interactive brokers TWS API Python Get Account Balance

Tags: python, api, tws

I am trying to get account balance and store it as a varible.
The accountSummary value has the balance in it.
I am using print to verify the var bal has the data stored in it.
Print(bal) will display the information in the terminal but won't print it to file balance.txt.
If the orderid example from the earlier executed code is working correctly why not the Balance?

```
from ibapi import wrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.utils import iswrapper #just for decorator
from ibapi.common import *
import math
import os.path
from os import path

class TestApp(wrapper.EWrapper, EClient):
    posns = []
    fname = 'fname.txt'
    def __init__(self):
        wrapper.EWrapper.__init__(self)
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)

    @iswrapper
    def nextValidId(self, orderId:int):
        print("setting nextValidOrderId: %d", orderId)
        self.nextValidOrderId = orderId
        file = open("orders.txt","w")
        file.write(str(orderId))
        file.close()
        # here is where you start using api
        self.reqAccountSummary(9002, "All", "$LEDGER")

  
    @iswrapper
    def accountSummary(self, reqId:int, account:str, tag:str, value:str, currency:str):
        bal=(value)
    
        file = open("Balance.txt","w")
        file.write(bal)
        file.close()
   

   

    @iswrapper
    def accountSummaryEnd(self, reqId:int):
        
        # now we can disconnect
        self.disconnect()
   
def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7497, clientId=123)
    app.run()

  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting the file every time and not looking for Balance.  Use this

```
def accountSummary(self, reqId:int, account:str, tag:str, value:str, currency:str):
    if tag == "CashBalance": # or whatever you want
        with open('Balance.txt', 'a+') as file: #append, create if doesn't exist
            file.write("%s, %s, %s, %s\n" % (account, tag, value, currency))
```

Comment: Thank you again Brian!